# How to let terraform google compute instance group manager create instances not at same time

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cassandra, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm trying to use terraform to create a cassandra cluster by using google_compute_instance_group_manager. I can use this group manager to create multiple instances at same time. But the problem comes from start-up script. When I tried to add a cassandra data node into cassandra master cluster. This ADD operation cannot happened at same time. But when I created multiple instances by using group_manager. The start-up script will always run in parallel. And this will cause only one node can join the cassandra cluster.

I tried to add some random sleep in start-up script to avoid conflict but this will cause infrastructure unpredictable. Also I tried to create one instance at beginning then update or add more instances into cluster. But the GCP will assign a new IP to all restart/replace instance in cluster. And this will confuse cassandra master node a lot.

So I'm not sure if anyone knows how to let google compute group manager create node in some order or if there is any better way to let GPC run script at different time stamp after instance created to avoid conflict.
Terraform file

```
resource "google_compute_health_check" "autohealing" {
  name                = "autohealing-health-check"
  check_interval_sec  = 5
  timeout_sec         = 5
  healthy_threshold   = 2
  unhealthy_threshold = 10 # 50 seconds

  http_health_check {
    request_path = "/healthz"
    port         = "8080"
  }
}

resource "google_compute_instance_template" "instance_template" {
  name_prefix = "cassandra-template-"
  machine_type = var.machine_type
  region = var.region

  disk {
    // Instance Templates reference disks by name, not self link
    source_image = "centos-7" 
    auto_delete = false
    boot        = false
  } 

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }

  network_interface {
    network = "cassandra-network"
  }

  metadata = {
    cassandra_seed = "${var.CASSANDRA_SEED}"
  }

  metadata_startup_script = file("startup.sh")
}

resource "google_compute_instance_group_manager" "instance_group_manager" {
  name               = "cassandra-slave-manager"
  base_instance_name = "cassandra-slave-manager"
  zone               = var.zone

  version {
     name = "instance_group_manager"
     instance_template = google_compute_instance_template.instance_template.self_link
  }

  target_size       = "3" // When this size > 1 only one instance can join to cassandra cluster

  update_policy {
    type                  = "PROACTIVE"
    minimal_action        = "RESTART"
    max_surge_fixed       = "1"
    max_unavailable_fixed = "1"
  }
}
```

Start up script

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo yum install docker -y
sudo systemctl start docker
export SEED=$(curl "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/attributes/cassandra_seed" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google")
export LISTEN_ADDRESS=$(hostname -i)
sleep $[ ( $RANDOM % 10 )  + 1 ]s
sudo docker run --name cas1 --network host \
    -e CASSANDRA_SEEDS=$SEED \
    -e CASSANDRA_LISTEN_ADDRESS=$LISTEN_ADDRESS \
    -e CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME=MyCluster \
    -e CASSANDRA_START_RPC=true \
    -e CASSANDRA_RPC_ADDRESS=$LISTEN_ADDRESS \
    -e CASSANDRA_DC=datacenter1 \
    -e CASSANDRA_ENDPOINT_SNITCH=GossipingPropertyFileSnitch \
    -d cassandra
```

Local run script

```
echo "Start CASSANDRA Cluster"
    echo "Start Master Node"
    cd terraform_cassandra
    terraform init
    terraform apply -auto-approve

    echo "Start Slave Nodes"
    export CASSANDRA_SEED=$(gcloud --format="value(networkInterfaces[0].networkIP)" compute instances list --filter=cassandra-vm-master)
    cd ../terraform_cassandra_slave_gm/
    terraform init
    terraform apply -auto-approve -var "CASSANDRA_SEED="$CASSANDRA_SEED
```

errors

```
-- StackTrace --
java.lang.AssertionError
    at org.apache.cassandra.locator.TokenMetadata.getTokens(TokenMetadata.java:474)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.getTokens(StorageService.java:2263)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.getTokens(StorageService.java:2252)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:112)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:46)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanIntrospector.invokeM(MBeanIntrospector.java:237)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.PerInterface.getAttribute(PerInterface.java:83)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanSupport.getAttribute(MBeanSupport.java:206)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getAttribute(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:647)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.getAttribute(JmxMBeanServer.java:678)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1445)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.getAttribute(RMIConnectionImpl.java:639)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor20.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:324)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Please provide more information: terraform configuration files, start-up scripts and your steps one by one with errors you got. It'll help to figure your problem out. BTW, you can  install cassandra cluster from Market.

Comment: I think the issue comes from casssandra set up. Cause cassandra does not support join multiple data nodes into cluster at same time. And terraform group manager will trigger multiple nodes creation at same time.